# NTFS permissions equivalent to Linux "--x" (chmod 111)

Tags: ntfs, file-permissions

I want to  set `folder` with permissions such that restricted users could access `file.txt` (in `folder`) they have permissions to read by specifying full path but could not list the content of `folder`.

For example, in Linux, we could do it like this:

```
$ whoami
cychoi
$ mkdir folder && echo 'file content' > folder/file.txt
$ chmod 111 folder/
$ sudo ls -la folder/
total 12
d--x--x--x 2 cychoi cychoi 4096 Aug 18 21:52 .
drwx------ 3 cychoi cychoi 4096 Aug 18 21:52 ..
-rw------- 1 cychoi cychoi   13 Aug 18 21:52 file.txt
$ ls folder/
ls: cannot open directory folder/: Permission denied
$ cat folder/file.txt
file content
$
```

In Windows 7, I clear all permissions of `folder` except `execute/traverse` (Apply to "this folder only"). However, It fails to read the content of `file.txt` even full path is specified.

On the other hand, if `read data/list directory` is also set for `folder`, `file.txt` will be read successfully but `folder` content will be leaked to restricted users.

```
G:\ptest>whoami
user-pc\test

G:\ptest>runas /u:administrator "cmd /c icacls g:\ptest\folder\ /t & pause"
Enter the password for administrator:
Attempting to start cmd /c icacls g:\ptest\folder\ /t & pause as user "USER-PC\administrator" ...

g:\ptest\folder\ user-PC\test:(S,X)
                 BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 user-PC\cychoi:(OI)(CI)(F)

g:\ptest\folder\file.txt user-PC\test:(F)
                         BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                         user-PC\cychoi:(I)(F)

G:\ptest>dir
 Volume in drive G is ?????
 Volume Serial Number is DEAD-BEEF

 Directory of G:\ptest

18/08/2015  21:59              .
18/08/2015  21:59              ..
18/08/2015  21:59              folder
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)   4,779,642,880 bytes free

G:\ptest>dir folder
 Volume in drive G is ?????
 Volume Serial Number is DEAD-BEEF

 Directory of G:\ptest\folder

File Not Found

G:\ptest>type folder\file.txt
Access is denied.

G:\ptest>runas /u:administrator "cmd /c icacls g:\ptest\folder\ /grant test:(rd) & pause"
Enter the password for administrator:
Attempting to start cmd /c icacls g:\ptest\folder\ /grant test:(rd) & pause as user "USER-PC\administrator" ...

G:\ptest>runas /u:administrator "cmd /c icacls g:\ptest\folder\ & pause"
Enter the password for administrator:
Attempting to start cmd /c icacls g:\ptest\folder\ & pause as user "USER-PC\administrator" ...


g:\ptest\folder\ user-PC\test:(S,RD,X)
                 BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
                 user-PC\cychoi:(OI)(CI)(F)

G:\ptest>dir folder
 Volume in drive G is ?????
 Volume Serial Number is DEAD-BEEF

 Directory of G:\ptest\folder

18/08/2015  21:59              .
18/08/2015  21:59              ..
18/08/2015  21:59                12 file.txt
               1 File(s)             12 bytes
               2 Dir(s)   4,779,642,880 bytes free

G:\ptest>type folder\file.txt
file content
G:\ptest>
```

So, how can I achieve the same behaviour as in the Linux example I shown above?

Comment: `/grant test:(OI)(IO)R`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks. Tried but I still get `access is denied` when trying to read `file.txt`.

Comment: FYI, `folder user-PC\test:(OI)(IO)(R)  user-PC\test:(S,X)` `folder\file.txt user-PC\test:(I)(R)`

Comment: You get `access is denied` when you use `type folder\file.txt`? Try something else, like `notepad folder\file.txt`. As I check with Process Monitor, `type` get `ACCESS DENIED` on folder and does not even try to open file.

Comment: All Windows versions since NT 4.ish actually let users [_bypass_ all traverse checking](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/10/19/the-bypass-traverse-checking-or-is-it-the-change-notify-privilege.aspx). So the `(X)` permission on directories is there just for show (and for older & non-Windows systems). So your problem isn't in the permissions. As PetSerAl noticed, it's cmd.exe doing what it shouldn't, then blaming the wrong thing.